# Typesetting the square of a mathematical operator

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

Assume I want to typeset the square of some mathematical operator A. Using `\operatorname` ([`amsmath`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) package), there are basically two ways to do that:

1. `\(\operatorname{A^{2}}\)` (i.e., the exponent is considered part of the operator name)
2. `\(\operatorname{A}^{2}\)` (i.e., the exponent is not considered part of the operator name)

According to my tests, the above two formulae are not equivalent, though. In fact, the first formula has a smaller height than the second one. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\len}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \settoheight{\len}{\(\operatorname{A^{2}}\)}
  \(\operatorname{A^{2}}\): height = \the\len
\item
  \settoheight{\len}{\(\operatorname{A}^{2}\)}
  \(\operatorname{A}^{2}\): height = \the\len
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody explain what is at the bottom of my observation?

Comment: This issue is due to how TeX handles operators. An operator is boxed, so subscript placement is different than for normal characters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that TeX typesets superscripts differently whether it follows a character or a box, as described in rule 18a of Appendix G of *The TeXbook*. As the macro `\operatorname` boxes its contents (because it calls `\mathop` which does), that's why `\operatorname{A}^2` and `\operatorname{A^2}` differ (the first superscript concerns a box, whereas the second only the preceding A). You can easily see that an `\operatorname` and an `\hbox` behave similarly:

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\scalebox{5}{$\operatorname{A}^2$} & \scalebox{5}{$\hbox{A}^2$} & \scalebox{5}{$\operatorname{A^2}$} \\
\verb"$\operatorname{A}^2$" & \verb"$\hbox{A}^2$" & \verb"$\operatorname{A^2}$" \\
\end{tabular}

\raisebox{1.22cm}[0pt]{\color{red}\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\end{document}
```

---

Here are the technical details of the actual computations made by TeX in the present case:

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\setbox0=\hbox{$a$}% to initialize the maths fonts

\begingroup
\newdimen\h
\newdimen\q
\newdimen\boxedu
\newdimen\unboxedu
\newdimen\sigmafourteen
\newdimen\sigmafive
\q=\the\fontdimen18\scriptfont2
\sigmafourteen=\the\fontdimen14\textfont2
\sigmafive=\the\fontdimen5\textfont2
\def\tabularheading{\itshape\color{red!70!black}}

\noindent List of relevant font parameters and their values:
\begin{quote}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\tabularheading Name & \tabularheading Symbol & \tabularheading Value \\
\texttt{x\_height} & $\sigma_5$ & \the\sigmafive \\
\texttt{sup2}      & $\sigma_{14}$ & \the\sigmafourteen \\
\texttt{sup\_drop} & $q$ (it's $\sigma_{18}$ of superscript font) & \the\q \\
\end{tabular}
\end{quote}
Comparison of the amount the superscript is shifted up for a boxed and unboxed $A$:
\begin{quote}
\setbox0=\hbox{$A$}
\h=\the\ht0
\def\maxof#1#2{%
  \ifdim#1>#2%
      #1%
    \else
      #2%
    \fi}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
& \tabularheading Boxed $A$ & \tabularheading Unboxed $A$ \\
\tabularheading height $h$ & \the\h & \the\h \\
\tabularheading base superscript shift $u_0$ & $h-q = \mathrm{\the\dimexpr\h-\q\relax}$ & 0pt \\
\tabularheading real shift $u = \max(u_0,\sigma_{14},\frac{1}{4}\sigma_5)$ &
\boxedu=\dimexpr\h-\q\relax
\boxedu=\maxof{\boxedu}{\sigmafourteen}%
\global\boxedu=\maxof{\boxedu}{.25\sigmafive}%
\the\boxedu
&
\unboxedu=0pt
\unboxedu=\maxof{\unboxedu}{\sigmafourteen}%
\global\unboxedu=\maxof{\unboxedu}{.25\sigmafive}%
\the\unboxedu
\end{tabular}
\end{quote}
Comparision of the calculations with the real typesetting:
\begin{quote}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\scalebox{5}{$\hbox{$A$}^2$\hbox{$A$\raise\boxedu\hbox{$\scriptstyle2$}}} & \scalebox{5}{$A^2$\hbox{$A$\raise\unboxedu\hbox{$\scriptstyle2$}}} \\
\tabularheading boxed $A$ & \tabularheading unboxed $A$ \\
\end{tabular}

\raisebox{1.35cm}[0pt]{\color{blue}\rule{9.5cm}{0.4pt}}
\end{quote}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’ve done some further tests. `\hbox{<base>}^{<exponent>}` doesn’t behave the same as `\mathop{<base>}^{<exponent>}`. However, `\operatorname` internally uses something like `\mathop{\kern0pt<base>}^{<exponent>}`, and, in fact, this matches the behaviour of `\hbox{<base>}^{<exponent>}`.

Comment: @mhp: do you have an example of `\hbox{<base>}^{<exponent>}` being different than `\mathop{<base>}^{<exponent>}`? Because you must be careful of what `\mathop` does that `\hbox` doesn't (it shifts single characters to the math axis) and of what `\hbox` does and `\mathop` doesn't (put the type in roman). This should normally account for the differences you saw.

Comment: Try `\settoheight{\len}{\(\hbox{A}^{2}\)}` vs. `\settoheight{\len}{\(\mathrm{\mathop{A}^{2}}\)}`. Moreover, you’ll see the same effect if you replace `\mathop` with `\mathord`.

Comment: @mhp: nothing unexpected happening here. Measuring is not enough, you should see what formulas look like. The `2` is low in `\mathrm{\mathop{A}^{2}}` because the `A` is in fact below the baseline as you see if you type `\mathrm{A^2\mathop{A}^{2}}`. As for `\mathord` giving the same result as `\mathop` height-wise, that's normal as `{A}`, `\mathord{A}` and `A` are all the same thing and, in `\mathrm{\mathop{A}^{2}}`, the `2` is as low as it can be just as in `A^2`. The `\kern0pt` in `\operatorname` is here for only one reason: avoiding that `\operatorname{A}` go below baseline.

Comment: OK, so `\mathop` always boxes its content whereas `\mathord` boxes its content if there is more than one character, right?

Comment: @mhp: something else than only one character, yes.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a fairly detailed explanation of what goes on in the execution of an `\operatorname` instruction. Note that this explanation is simplified to the case of the use of this command *without* the `*` ("star") qualifier. (See `amsopn.sty` for the full details.)

The `\operatorname` instruction (without the "star" qualifier) is set up as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\operatorname}{{\qopname\newmcodes@ o}}
```

where `\qopname`, in turn, is defined as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
    \mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}%
    \csname n#2limits@\endcsname},
```

`\operator@font` is given by

```
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symoperators},
```

and `\newmcodes@` is given -- inside a TeX group for which `"` has catcode 12 -- by

```
\gdef\newmcodes@{\mathcode`\'39\mathcode`\*42\mathcode`\."613A%
  \ifnum\mathcode`\-=45 \else
    \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
  \fi
  \mathcode`\-45\mathcode`\/47\mathcode`\:"603A\relax}
```

(Basically, the `\newmcodes@` command modifies the meanings to the characters `'` `*` `.` `-` `/` and `:` from their "regular" math-mode settings.) Finally, the command `\z@` is equivalent to `0pt` (zero length).

Hence, executing the command `\operatorname{xyz}` is equivalent to executing

```
{\qopname\newmcodes@ o xyz}
```

which boils down to executing, after (i) recognizing that none of the special characters affected by the `\newmodes@` command are involved in the current example, (ii) resolving the construct in the `\csname ... \endcsname` complex to `\nolimits`, and (iii) noting that `\nolimits` has no effects if we don't specify limits:

```
{\mathop{\kern0pt \operator@font xyz}
```

Therefore, `$\operatorname{A}^2$` resolves to

```
${\mathop{\kern0pt \operator@font A}^2$
```

whereas `$\operatorname{A^2}$` resolves to

```
${\mathop{\kern0pt \operator@font A^2}$
```

If the "squaring instruction" is *inside* the `\mathop` instruction, it appears that the height of the letter(s) that precede the superscript-2 do not affect the vertical positioning of the `2`. E.g., check out the positions of the `2` glyph in

```
$\mathop{\kern0pt \operator@font ln^2}$
$\mathop{\kern0pt \operator@font sin^2}$
$\mathop{\kern0pt \operator@font cos}^2$`
```

They're all the same.

Conversely, if the "squaring instruction" is *not inside* the `\mathop` instruction, what comes into play is the height of the entire box that contains the "name" part of the `\operatorname` instruction; if the "name" part contains letters with ascenders, the box's height increases, and this will affect the positioning of the superscript-2. E.g., for `$\ln^2$`, `$\det^2$`, and `$\cos^2$`, the superscript is at different heights because of the differences in the heights of the boxes that contain `ln`, `sin`, and `cos`, respectively.

Comment: @mhp: I've revised my answer thoroughly to track in all gory detail what exactly goes on in the execution of the \operatorname command.

Comment: The placing of superscripts is not affected by the presence of absence of ascenders when applied to characters, the vertical position of the superscript `x^2` and `X^2` will be the same. On the other hand, when applied to boxes the height of the box is taken into account, so `{xx}^2` and `{XX}^2` are different.

Comment: @mhp: not always: `{A}^2` gives the same result as `A^2`. But as soon as there is something else than one character inside the braces, it becomes boxed content, so the behavior is perfectly normal as all boxed content behave the same.

Comment: @KhaledHosny -- thanks for providing this clarification. I'll update my answer to incorporate the importance of thinking in terms of boxes.

Comment: @Mico: If I understand you right the last two paragraphs of your answer are contradictory to the answer of Philippe Goutet.

Comment: @mhp - I don't think there's a conflict between our answers. Where do you see a contradiction arising?

Comment: @Mico: your two paragraphs have the two situations mixed up. The case where TeX takes into account the height of all the letters before the `^2` is `\mathop{sin}^2` (so when the squarring is *outside*, not *inside*). In the case of`\mathop{sin^2}`, the `^2` only concerns the last letter `n` so the preceding letters are not taken into account.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet - thanks for clearing up this confusion! I'll correct my writeup right away.

Comment: @Mico: a minor detail (it doesn't change what happens here) I notice when rereading your answer: due to how macro arguments work, `\qopname\newmcodes@ o {xyz}` becomes `\mathop{\kern0pt \operator@font xyz}` without braces around the `xyz`. You can see this by looking in the log file the result of `\makeatletter\showtokens\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname qopname \endcsname\newmcodes@ o {xyz}}`.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet -- thanks for providing these additional comments. I've made the required changes.

Answer (score 3):

You got some great answers explaining the TeXnicalities (and thus answering your question). I'd like to point out that you should *never* use `\(\operatorname{A^{2}}\)`, and that you probably just want `\(A^2\)`:

If you have some mathematical operator, then you can use the *variable* A to denote that operator. In that case you should just use `A^2`. Only for special (non-variable) operators one should use `\operatorname`, e.g. `\operatorname{E}` for the [expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). (In this example it happens that `\operatorname{E}^{2}` doesn't really make sense, but you'd always put the square *outside* the `\operatorname`.)

Comment: Of course, you’re right. But, as a matter of fact, `\operatorname` is not only used for real operators, but also for functions such as *sin*, *log* etc.

Comment: By the way, I think you mean ‘you should never use `\(\operatorname{A^{2}}\)`’, right?

Comment: @mhp: Oh my god, I wrote it the wrong way - thanks for pointing that out. Corrected!

Comment: @mhp: Of course, `\operatorname` is used for special (non-variable) functions, too. I thought I didn't need to mention that - an operator is a just a function, after all.