# Combining \operatorname with \mathnormal and \mathrm

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, subscripts, superscripts

> **Related Question:**
>   [Typesetting the square of a mathematical operator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67949/7160)

`\operatorname` converts its argument into a function symbol with appropriate spaces on the left and on the right. However, I often need sub- and superscripts applied on those symbols. So I'd like to define something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand\f[2]{
    \operatorname{\mathnormal{f}_{\mathnormal{#1}}^{\mathnormal{#2}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \f{2}{n}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\operatorname{\mathnormal{f}}_{#1}^{#2}` (sub- and superscript outside `\operatorname`) would place the subscript too far away from the letter `f`.

Here the problem begins: Since `\operatorname` internally applies `\mathrm` to its argument, `\f{2}{n}` typesets the exponent `n` upright:

[image: error1]

On the other hand, if I write

```
\newcommand\f[2]{
    \operatorname{\mathnormal{f}_{\mathnormal{#1}}^{\mathnormal{#2}}}
}
```

then the numbers' font is changed:

[image: error2]

This gets really tricky when combining letters (or other operators) and numbers like `\f{2mn\cdot x}{\frac{c}{2}}`:

[image: error3]

Is there a way to get the "right" letters **and** the "right" numbers at the same time?
That is:
[image: desired]

Comment: Can you please explain _why_ you want to use `\operatorname`, instead of just typing `f_2^n`?

Comment: Because of the spacing: E.g. `a\f{2}{n}+b` is different from `a\f{2}{n}+b`.

Comment: OK, that's true. I'm still not sure why you want that different spacing - that would be interesting to know.

Comment: The idea is simply to highlight function symbols in somewhat lengthy equations, such that it is easier to determine which symbols are functions, constants and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the info! (Let me mention that it might be OK to do this for educational purposes, but not in usual typesetting.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what layout you want, (perhaps a full minimal example and image in your question would have helped).

The main function of `\operatorname` is to provide multi-letter operators like log etc, if you want a math italic f it seems that you just need one of these, depending on where you want the limits to go.

The other function is to give it operator spacing, ie a small gap before the argument, so perhaps the first or second form is what you are looking for?

```
$ f_1^2 x $

$ \mathop{f_1^2} x $

$ \mathop{{}f}_1^2 x $

$ \mathop{{}f}\limits_1^2 x $
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I extended my question such that my problem should be quite clear now.

Comment: Your first suggestion puts the subscript `1` not close enough to the `f`, just like `\operatorname{\mathnormal{f}}_{#1}^{#2}`. The second one is, unfortunately, also not the desired solution as I don't want the operator to show limits.

Comment: it's not close because operatorname gives it mathop spacing which forces a gap, I updated my answer with a variant without that.

Comment: Oh updated answer again. I think it's the 2nd form you want with the 1 still kerned back to the f and operator spacing for the whole constrruct

Comment: Thanks. The second form solves my problem. `\operatorname{foo}` reduces to `\mathop{\kern0pt \operator@font foo}` where `\operator@font` caused my problem. For anyone who is interested in the details, I refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67956/7160