# `\DeclareMathOperator` internals

Tags: macros, amsmath, math-operators

I ask two questions below, which are unified in a third meta-question.  Thanks to @DavidCarlisle's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572126/declaremathoperator-internals#comment1441573_572126), I realise that my questions are such that the answer may depend on whether they are interpreted in the context of MathJax or of LaTeX+`amsmath`.  I am interested in answers in both contexts.

I am constantly on the hunt to impose (my admittedly self defined) best practices on the sometimes baroque TeX that crops up at [MO](http://mathoverflow.net).  A lot of times this involves changing, say, `$Hom(A, B)$` to `$\operatorname{Hom}(A, B)$`, and I often leave a note for a new user letting them know about `\DeclareMathOperator` and siblings.

I noticed on one post that a user had picked up this advice with a twist, and started using `\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}`.

**Q**:  Is `\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}` synonymous with `\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}`?

I have recently noticed another user who used a construction like `\DeclareMathOperator\Set{\mathit{Set}}`.

**Q**:  Is `\DeclareMathOperator\Set{\mathit{Set}}` synonymous with `\newcommand\Set{\mathit{Set}}`?  If not, then is it synonymous with `\newcommand\Set{\mathop{\mathit{Set}}}`?

Obviously there's a meta-question lurking here, which I would be able to answer if I were more comfortable diving into—I guess it is—the `amsmath` source:

**Q**:  On the level of code, not just the big picture "this is what you want for an operator name", what do `\DeclareMathOperator` and `\operatorname` do?

Comment: Note that if you are asking about MathOverflow, the details of the tex internals of the latex definitions of these commands are not relevant as that is using Javascript not TeX, can you clarify whether "on the level of code" you are asking about tex or mathjax?

Comment: the amsmath source is quite readable and is a typeset document, try `texdoc amsmath.pdf`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572126/declaremathoperator-internals#comment1441573_572126) is a good point.  I assumed that the translation to MathJax was literal enough that synonymy on the level of TeX code would translate into synonymy on the level of MathJax, but, now that you've pointed it out, I guess even my unifying meta-question is two questions.  I am interested in both (although I'm about to go read the `amsmath` source, so maybe that will answer one of the questions if I am suitably clever to understand it).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I find on looking in `amsopn.pdf` (to which `amsmath.pdf` directs me for `\DeclareMathOperator`) that I need to understand, to get even one level deep, `\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{\mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}\csname n#2limits@\endcsname}` and `\gdef\newmcodes@{\mathcode‘\’39\mathcode‘\*42\mathcode‘\."613A%`, which are beyond me in many ways.  (For example, I don't understand where the terminating brace in `\newmcodes@` is.)  So I guess my (newly bifurcated) question stands.

Comment: mathjax definitions are usually unrelated to tex definitions of commands of the same name, it is in no sense a translation. the main difference is not just that it is written in javascript, but it is written in terms of (essentially) mathml javascript objects and the css layout model, whereas latex definitions are written involving catcodes and tex's box and glue layout model, so apart from the top level names and documented behaviour, there is usually nothing in common, and behaviour of undocumented edge cases as in some of the examples you show is quite likely different.

Comment: @LSpice - If you hanker to understand the deep details of `\operatorname`, do check out [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67956/5001). :-)

Comment: @Mico, great!  So [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572126/declaremathoperator-internals/572154#comment1441610_572126) seems like an answer to my meta-question as long as, as seems to be the case, `\DeclareMathOperator\cs{tokens}` is synonymous with `\newcommand\cs{\operatorname{tokens}}` (when `\cs` is undefined).  Is that so?

Comment: @Mico, [it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572126/declaremathoperator-internals/572154#comment1441610_572126) would also answer my first question if it then explained whether `\operatorname` is idempotent, in the sense that `\operatorname{\operatorname{Hom}}` is synonymous with `\operatorname{Hom}`.  I cannot yet tell that from your answer (probably just haven't absorbed it yet).  Do you know if it is so?

Comment: @LSpice  - On your first comment: I believe the main practical difference is that `\DeclareMathOperator{\xyz}{xyz}` defines a "robust" macro called `\xyz`, whereas `\newcommand\xyz{\operatorname{xyz}}` creates a potentially non-robust macro. On the second comment: I hadn't thought of "idempotency" in the context of (recursive) macro definition, but I think it's a remarkably apt term. (Well, idempotency *might* fail if the tokens contain some devious low-level font-size changing commands.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll not touch MathJax, because its model is completely different from LaTeX.

#### First question

Something like `\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}` of course works, but `\Hom` will do twice the same things. In `amsopn.sty`, we find

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\operatorname}{%
  \@ifstar{\qopname\newmcodes@ m}%
          {\qopname\newmcodes@ o}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
  \mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}%
  \csname n#2limits@\endcsname}
\newcommand{\DeclareMathOperator}{%
  \@ifstar{\@declmathop m}{\@declmathop o}}
\long\def\@declmathop#1#2#3{%
  \@ifdefinable{#2}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#2}{\qopname\newmcodes@#1{#3}}}}
```

Assuming that `\foo` is undefined, `\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{???}` does

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{\qopname\newmcodes@ o{???}}
```

which is a shortened version of

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}{\operatorname{???}}
```

On the other hand, `\operatorname{+++}` will do

```
\qopname\newmcodes@ o{+++}
```

Hence your `\Hom` would do

```
\qopname\newmcodes@ o{\qopname\newmcodes@ o{Hom}}
```

which seems quite complicated for nothing: it's essentially the same as doing

```
\operatorname{\operatorname{Hom}}
```

each time `\Hom` is used.

#### Second question

The definitions

```
\DeclareMathOperator\Set{\mathit{Set}}
\newcommand\Set{\mathit{Set}}
\newcommand\Set{\mathop{\mathit{Set}}}
```

will do different things. We can see the differences with a simple example

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
x \operatorname{\mathit{Set}}_2 y\\
x \mathit{Set}_2 y \\
x \mathop{\mathit{Set}}_2 y
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

The answer to your first question shows that `\foo` after `\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}` is the same as using `\operatorname{foo}`, so line (1) is the same as you'd get from `\DeclareMathOperator{\Set}{\mathit{Set}}`.

[image]

Are they the same? No.

#### Third question

Use `\operatorname` in the document for operators that appear one or two times. For operators that are used several times, add the appropriate `\DeclareMathOperator` line, in order to ease typing and reduce clutter.

#### Addendum

I leave to you as an exercise to find the differences between

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\tlim}{t-lim}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\tlim}{\mathop{t-lim}}
```

Comment: Note that (as you of course know) one can get `\mathop` spacing without the log-like subscript in (3) with `\mathop{\mathit{Set}}\nolimits`.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, I know, but I answered the OP's question. ;-) On the other hand `\mathop{a-b}` and `\operatorname{a-b}` will output *very* different things.

Comment: Ah, good old hyphen-minus, doing double duty.

Comment: You definitely answered my second question, but I'm not entirely sure you answered the first or the third.  The first question was:  Is `\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}` synonymous with `\DeclareMathOpator\Hom{Hom}`?  If I understand correctly, you instead answered:  Is `\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}` synonymous with `\newcommand\Hom{\operatorname{\operatorname{Hom}}`?  For the third, you seem to have explained when to use `\DeclareMathOperator` and when to use `\operatorname`, which is general macro-style advice; but I was interested in getting into the weeds …

Comment: … in the sense of the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67956) that @Mico [links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572126/declaremathoperator-internals/572154#comment1441610_572126), of what `\DeclareMathOperator` actually *does*, not when to use it.  It sounds to me like you are saying: in general, without having to understand, say, `\newmcodes@`, `\DeclareMathOperator\cs{tokens}` is synonymous with `\newcommand\cs{\operatorname{tokens}}` (assuming `\cs` is undefined).  Is that correct?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, they're *almost* the same; they'll be the same with `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand` (but with `\DeclareMathOperator` you get a slightly more efficient macro).

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't accept this after you [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572126/declaremathoperator-internals#comment1441782_572154) my [reservation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572126/declaremathoperator-internals#comment1441742_572154).  Anyway, I have done so now.  Thank you!